# Clarification of Puppeteer instances on aws lambda

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, puppeteer, chromium

I am running puppeteer on aws lambda and have 2 questions:

1. Every time I invoke puppeteer.launch(), a new browser instance is created. Let’s say there is no code to browser.close() after finishing using puppeteer. Will the browser instance still stay alive as a running process?
2. Assuming no browser.close() and the existing running instance is still there when a new request comes to the lambda, will puppeteer.launch() create another browser process or will it use the browser instance created in a previous request? Is there any way to check for that in code?
   Thanks.